# Can we manually implement What branch provides us

Tags: android, ios, node.js, deep-linking

I am trying to manually implement what branch io provides as a service. I have implemented the deeplink and it works well in both android and ios.

Basically what I am trying to do is not the whole thing what branch io does. But when a user clicks a link or button in my website which contains a deeplink `(ex: myapp://application/1)`  I want to detect whether my application has installed on the device and if it is not, I want to check the os (Android or iOS) and redirect the user to play store or apple store to download my app. And if that deep link is accessed through a desktop browser I want to redirect the user to a different web page containing instructions on what to do. If it is a mobile device and if the app is installed I want to open the deeplink through the app.

What I am trying to achieve is when user clicks the button or link for the deeplink; redirect the specific id of that link to the server and check for the OS, and check for whether the app is installed and then work accordingly. So far apart from the deeplink part I have been able to check for users OS and whether it is a mobile device or not. I have no idea on how to check whether the app is installed or not. But assuming the app is installed I tried to redirect the user to the deeplink from the server but as I have used a unique schema for my deeplinks rather than `http or https` I cannot redirect to the deeplink. I cannot use universal links for deeplinks as iOS9 universal links does not support in some applications and have different conditions on using safari or chrome.

(Attached image is from branch tutorial on changing to universal links)
[image: Universal Link support in iOS]

What I am trying to do now is to communicate with the device and check for unique id or something that could be implemented inside myapp so that I can get to know whether the app is installed or not. I have no clue on what I am doing and is stuck still at the beginning.

If someone could help me in achieving this it would be a great help for me.

I am using nodejs and express in server side.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this is definitely a big project! May I ask why you're wanting to implement it from scratch?

Comment: @AlexBauer I am working at a tech startup and the company seems to have many improvement ideas along the path. For that they want to use and do everything within the company server. Therefore they want me to find a method to get things done from and within our server.